# Divide one cell on x axis into four parts using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Using Chart.js, I would like to use X-axis for each day. Within each day, there are four parts of its day eg. 6 hours range of the day starting from 3am - 9am, 9am - 3pm, 3pm - 9pm, 9pm - 3am, so that there should be 4 intervals for each day on X-axis.
I've tried to get this concept by using top X-axis and bottom X-axis.
But I only got one cell for each interval in top X-axis, I don't want this.
Actually, I want one cell for top X-axis should be for four cells of bottom X-axis. 
My sample code is as following.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
  var options = {
    
    scales: {
      xAxes: [

        {
          id: 'xAxis1',
          position: 'bottom',
          type: "category",
          gridLines: {
            display: false
          },
          ticks: {
            userCallback: function(item, index) {
              return item.split(';')[0];
            },
            fontSize: 8
          }
        },
        {
          id: 'xAxis2',
          position: 'top',
          type: "category",
          gridLines: {
            drawOnChartArea: false, // only want the grid lines for one axis to show up
            drawTicks: false
          },
          ticks: {
            callback: function(item, index) {
              //var month = label.split(";")[0];
              if (index % 4 == 0) return item.split(';')[1];
            },
            fontSize: 12
          }
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        },
      }]
    }
  };
  var color = 'rgba(255,182,193,0.5)';
  var mixedChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      datasets: [{
        label: 'AQI status Color',
        data: [36, 36, 36],
        backgroundColor: color,
      }, {
        label: 'AQI value',
        data: [10, 20, 30],
        fill: false,

        // Changes this dataset to become a line
        type: 'line'
      }],
      // labels: ['3;6;15;21;Mon', '3;6;15;21;Tue', '3;6;15;21;Wed', '3;6;15;21;Thu', '3;6;15;21;Fri']
      labels: ['3;Mon', '9;Mon', '15;Mon', '21;Mon', '3;Tue', '9;Tue', '15;Tue', '21;Tue',
        '3;Wed', '9;Wed', '15;Wed', '21;Wed', '3;Thu', '9;Thu', '15;Thu', '21;Thu',
        '3;Fri', '9;Fri', '15;Fri', '21;Fri'
      ],
    },
    options: options
  });
```

```html
<div style="width:600px;">
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
//your code

});

Comment: Hi, I added an include for chartjs so your code snippet would run. I just made the font size of the axis ticks bigger so I could read it. I see 1 tick on the top axis for every 4 ticks on the bottom. I don't understand from your question what you are trying to do instead of that

Comment: Currently having on tick on top X-axis for every four ticks on bottom X-axis is just workaround. I just want to group four ticks on bottom X-axis as one tick on top X-axis so that label on top axis will be between four ticks on bottom axis.